# ASP.NET MVC Passing URL id between views of different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I decided to make an auction house web application as my first asp.net mvc project and I cannot figure out how to pass a parameter between two views that belong to different controllers. In the first view, Details of AuctionHouseController, I have:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Create", "Auctions", new { id = Model.ItemId })">Start Auction &raquo;</a>
```

and a URL: http://localhost:2142/AuctionHouse/Details/123

And here is the Details method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var item = _auctionhDbc.Items.Find(id);
        return View(item);
    }
```

I want to pass the id part of the URL - the "123" to the view where the button leads - Create of AuctionsController, where I have:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item.ItemId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.ItemId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = " " } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item.ItemId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to place the "123" as the default value (@Value) of the Html Editor field. How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the `@Value = " " ` code. If the value of `Item.ItemId` is `123`, then it will be added automatically. You need to show your `Details(int ID)` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke 

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var item = _auctionhDbc.Items.Find(id);
            return View(item);
        }

Comment: Edit your question (not in comments). But the code in you comment does not appear to set the value of property `Item.ItemId` (and what is your model in the view? Based on what you have show you need `item.Item.ItemId = id;` which does not make much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using strongly typed views, your model for the `Create` view will already have the value of 123 in `ItemID`. The problem is, your model is of type `Items`, yet you are trying to use `EditorFor` for `model.Item.ItemID`.

Thus, instead of your line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.ItemId, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = " " } })
```

if you use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemId, 
        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

you will already have passed the value there. Make sure you use [strongly typed views](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) by putting:

```
@model YourNameSpace.Items
```

in the beginning of your view.

Comment: Great! 

What if I need to access other properties of the item, e.g. Item.ItemName?

Comment: whatever your model carries with it, you can access the same way. i.e. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.YourModelProperty)`

Comment: Consider also using a view model (a custom class for this) instead of your `DbContext` class `Items`. That way you will have more flexibility.

Comment: It helped me figure out the solution. :)